# XPATH help - finding text, then the following button a few divs later

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

XPATH newbie... I am trying to find text, then find the following button in a code block like below.
The ember numbers change so can't use those.  Need to find text within a span, then the next (following) button after that text is found.  Then click on that button.  In this case it's a contact button.

I've tried:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'Jason')]]/div/div/button
```

Also tried:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'Jason')]]/following-sibling::button
```

A code block example I am trying to search.

```
 <div data-test="e-list-item" data-e-id="Fdh348uF" class="material-list-tile e-list-item">
                <div class="e-name">
<a href="/embed/Gdfsdjfhd25d88/gallery/Fdh348uF" id="ember2539" class="ember-view">                    <span data-test="e-name">Jason Alamoa</span>
</a><!---->                </div>
<!---->                  <div id="ember2539" class="c-info ember-view">    <div class="c-icons">
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
    </div>

</div>
                <div class="e-actions">
                  <div class="e-action-buttons">
<!---->                            <div class="e-action">
                                  <button class="ssButton ssButtonPrimary v-button v " type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2540="2540">
      <i class="ssIcon-ok-sign ssIcon-large"></i>
      Contact
    </button>
 

<!---->
                            </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Update your HTML code - its structure is not clear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to *find `span` with specific text and following `button`*, the easiest way

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Jason')]/following::button
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that and got this message...  
o such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(), 'Jason')]/following::button"}


fName = web.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Jason')]/following::button")

fName.click() 


Any other thoughts?

Comment: My issue was that I had to learn to search in an iFRAME.  that was why it was unable to locate the element

Answer (score 0):

Based on HTML snippet provided following XPath could be used:

```
//div[./a/span[contains(.,'Jason')]]/following::div[@class="e-actions"]//button
```

Explanation:

```
//div[./a/span[contains(.,'Jason')]] => selects "div" with child "a" containing child "span" containing text "Jason"
/following::div[@class="e-actions"] => selects following "div" after the first one having attribute "class" with value "e-actions"
//button => selects "button" inside of the previous "div"
```

Comment: Thank you. This did not work for me unfortunately. There are many divs "above" this one.    Would that be why?

Comment: Had to search in an iFRAME.. that was why. Both solutions work!